# Adding ground to a isolated psu

Tags: ground, grounding, 12v

I am not an electrical engineer by any measure but am competent in circuit design/ building but have not been had any experience with 240v yet.

The problem I'm facing is I have a 240v to 12v (7.5amp) power supply that is isolated in a full plastic enclosure so there is no need for a mains side ground connection, but i want to use it in a project where it is enclosed in a aluminium case and there is no room for the plastic housing.

What I want to know is how would I go about adding a ground to the project so i dont get injured when using it. Do i just mount a IEC320 male chassis plug  to the frame and attach a wire from the plug ground to the frame then positive and negative to the psu with nylon stand offs.

Comment: Something that is mounted in a plastic enclosure may indeed require an earth connection. Your premise is wrong and dangerous.

Comment: @Andyaka I think you misunderstand (or maybe I misunderstand ?) but the supply is in a plastic housing and does not **have** a ground connection. Like a power brick with a "figure 8" mains connection, these are not grounded. The output is "floating" (sort of).

Comment: If the PSU does have a ground connection but you decide **not to connect it** then I agree with Andy that this is dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Do i just mount a IEC320 male chassis plug to the frame and attach a wire from the plug ground to the frame then positive and negative to the psu with nylon stand offs.*

Yes you could do that.

**If** the PSU you have **does not have a ground connection**, it should then be a double isolated unit and it should then have this logo:

[image]

Now you want to use it in a different case instead of using the present plastic case. Now your plastic isolation will be replaced by "air". So make sure the complete PSU is at least a couple of millimeters away from the case. I'd use at least 5 mm.

The PSU does not need a mains side ground connection even in this new grounded case.

Do indeed ground your aluminium case from the IEC320 plug for safety reasons. This is a **MUST DO**. Also connect the ground using a crimped connection, nut, bolt and a shake-proof washer:

[image]

So that the connection will not work itself loose over time due to shaking and temperature changes.

Since the **output** of the PSU is "floating" you can connect it any way you like but your suggestion is the best, just connect the - (minus) to the ground/chassis. This is done in allmost all equipment.